# Android O - websockets limitations

Tags: android

So this is rather a question and a request for advice.

With the introduction of the new Android O the developers will face a problem with background services.

My question is what if I use websockets service for my chat feature. Does it mean that I can no longer use it and migrate to push strategy?

If no than what changes I should do?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If your UI is in the foreground, you should have no problems using WebSockets, though you would not need a service if that's the only time that you need WebSockets.

If your service is a foreground service, you should have no new problems using WebSockets, though you still have all the problems that you have been dealing with previously (e.g., Doze mode). Also, you should reconsider the power implications of what you are doing.

If your service is not a foreground service, either make it be a foreground service or move your chat feature to be something that only operates when your UI is in the foreground.

Comment: I mean how does whatsap do it? it has clearly a background service.

Comment: @MikhailKim: I would assume that they are using FCM.

Comment: so the only way I can implement the chat that works in background is FCM now?